# Working with csv file and DateTime using datatable in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I have a .CSV file ([.csv file google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OeuBkkbd2xcSNs4JKNH_ErXr1Hpb1ot/view?usp=sharing)).

I have taken all values of csv file in DataTable.
Now what I am trying to do I am explaining below:

I am finding the lowest value of D column in csv file each and every 5 mins. And the each lowest value will be inserted to the first row of L column with 5 mins time interval.
You can get idea from [this csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YRM0RhKylNFgYR3KkTvrjmJ9lYB09hYU/view?usp=sharing). This csv file is output file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Revision2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable datable = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browsebtm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Select .CSV ffile";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            txtboxpath.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }

        private void operatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = txtboxpath.Text;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] value = line.Split(',');

            DataRow row;
            foreach (string dc in value)
            {
                datable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                if (value.Length == datable.Columns.Count)
                {
                    row = datable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = value;
                    datable.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }


            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(datable.Rows[0][1].ToString(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            int totalRows = datable.Rows.Count;
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(datable.Rows[totalRows - 1][1].ToString(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            DateTime i, j;
            int r = 0, x = 0, z = 0, value1, value2 = 0;
            for (i = dt1; i <= dt2; i = i.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                DateTime dt5 = i.AddMinutes(5);
                if (dt5 >= dt2)
                    break;
                int y = 0;
                for (j = i; j < dt5; j = j.AddSeconds(1))
                {
                    y++;
                    for (r = x; r < 1669; r++)
                    {


                        string str1 = datable.Rows[r][1].ToString();
                        string str2 = j.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm);
                        if (str1 == str2)
                        {

                            value1 = int.Parse(datable.Rows[r][3].ToString());
                            value2 = int.Parse(datable.Rows[x][3].ToString());
                            if (value2 > value1)
                            {
                                value2 = value1;
                            }
                            x++;
                        }
                    }
                    label2.Text = y.ToString();
                    if (r > 1669)
                        break;

                }
                datable.Rows[r][11] = value2;

            }
            label2.Text = i.ToString();
            //label1.Text = y.ToString();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = datable;
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing something wrong. When I am clicking operate button App is freezing.
How can I improve my code to do this.
I am new bie. Please help

Comment: start by stepping through the code with the debugger to identify more precisely where the problem occurs, and what, if any, exception or other unexpected behaviour you experience at that point.

Comment: In DataTable there are about 1670 rows...how can I check this through breakpoint

Comment: DataTable is not the right control for this job. Simply use Linq.

Comment: what is that?But the problem is not in DataTable , problem is in loop somewhere.

Comment: Cetin is pointing out that if you used Linq you probably wouldn't need a loop. Although it's not immediately obvious to me how the requirement would be achieved using Linq, I'd imagine it's possible with a bit of thought

Comment: I have not any knowledge of linq. If you help me to do code in Linq, It will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Regarding the debugger, if you at least run in debug mode it should stop on an exception instead of just freezing up.

Comment: you could just be in an infinite loop, why does your datetime parsing not have minutes?

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: yahh instead of second it will be minutes...but problem is still there

Comment: After sometime it is giving error ContextSwitchDeadlockOccurrred

Comment: Whats the point of the DataTable?  A collection of T would make it trivial to use linq to evaluate.  And of course there are tools aplenty to read, parse and convert CSV data to a collection for you.

Comment: What is that???

Comment: Can it be not done using data table?

Comment: separate your code in button_click by a Task. It takes a lot of time and freezes the UI.

Comment: Sorry...pkz explain... I am not able to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Linq doing these type of transformations are easier IMHO.
Here is the Linq sample (I downloaded your CSV to d:\temp\CRUDE1Minute.csv - you can copy&paste the below code and run it in LinqPad adding windows.forms namespace):

```
void Main()
{
    string fileName = @"d:\temp\CRUDE1Minute.csv";
    DateTime dt;
    var rawData = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .Select(line => new
        {
            TradingSymbol = line[0],
            SnapshotDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(line[1], "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", null,
                     System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : (DateTime?)null,
            Open = int.Parse(line[2]),
            Low = int.Parse(line[3]),
            High = int.Parse(line[4]),
            Close = int.Parse(line[5]),
            Volume = int.Parse(line[6]),
            SnapshotDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(line[1], "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", null,
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : (DateTime?)null,
            SnapshotTime = TimeSpan.Parse(line[8]),
            UpdateToDBTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(line[1], "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", null,
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : (DateTime?)null,
        });
        var result =
    from myData in rawData.OrderBy(t => t.SnapshotDateTime)
    let min5 = ((int)myData.SnapshotDateTime.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) / 5
    group myData by new
    {
        date = myData.SnapshotDateTime.Value.Date.AddMinutes(min5 * 5),
        min5
    } into barData
    select new
    {
        date = barData.Key.date,
        open = barData.Min( bd => bd.Open ),
        low = barData.Min(bd => bd.Low),
        high = barData.Min(bd => bd.High),
        close = barData.Min(bd => bd.Close)
    };

    var joined = from rd in rawData
                 join bd in result on rd.SnapshotDateTime equals bd.date into bdAdded
                 from d in bdAdded.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select           
    new {
         rd.TradingSymbol,
         rd.SnapshotDateTime,
         rd.Open,
         rd.Low,
         rd.High,
         rd.Close,
         rd.Volume,
         rd.SnapshotDate,
         rd.SnapshotTime,
         rd.UpdateToDBTime,
         bdOpen = d?.open,
         bdLow = d?.low,
         bdHigh = d?.high,
         bdClose = d?.close

    };


    // Show the result
    Form f = new Form();
    var dgv = new DataGridView {Dock=DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=joined.ToList()};
    f.Controls.Add( dgv);
    f.Show();
}
```

EDIT: BTW I was not clear about what you are selecting on those 5 min open, low, ... and may be wrong choosing Min on all. Maybe you want to do:

```
...
select new
{
    date = barData.Key.date,
    open = barData.First().Open, //barData.Min( bd => bd.Open ),
    low = barData.Min(bd => bd.Low),
    high = barData.Max(bd => bd.High),
    close = barData.Last().Close
};
```

Comment: how do u know my all requirement?

Comment: It helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop routine. I generally limit my nesting to 3 layers. In your case, you have 5 and it is terribly hard to follow.

```
int startIndex = 0;
while (startIndex < dt.Rows.Count)
{
    DateTime timeStart = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[startIndex][1].ToString(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime timeEnd = timeStart;
    int lowestValue = int.Parse(dt.Rows[startIndex][3].ToString());
    int endIndex = startIndex;

    //loop to find end index of 5 minute loop
    for (int j = startIndex++; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        endIndex = j;
        timeEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[endIndex][1].ToString(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if ((timeEnd - timeStart).TotalMinutes > 5)
        {
            break;
        }
        int newValue = int.Parse(dt.Rows[endIndex][3].ToString());
        if (newValue < lowestValue)
        {
            lowestValue = newValue;
        }
    }

    //loop from start to end to set lowest value
    for (var k = startIndex; k < endIndex; k++)
    {
        dt.Rows[k][11] = lowestValue.ToString();
    }

    startIndex = endIndex;
}
```